# SVG - reuse a line node with <def> and <use>

Tags: svg

My goal is to re-use a line node as follows:

```
<defs>
   <desc>x1 and x2 values never change, would like to provide y1 and y2 in use</desc>
   <line id="p" x1="5" x2="1019" stroke-width="1" stroke="#808080" opacity=".3"/>
</defs>

<use xlink:href="#p" y1="718.5" y2="718.5"/>
```

In learning SVG I thought any parameter provided in the use statement was passed to the template in the defs, but apparently not?  According to [W3 docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement):

> The ‘use’ element has optional attributes ‘x’, ‘y’, ‘width’ and ‘height’ which are used to map the graphical contents of the referenced element onto a rectangular region within the current coordinate system

However, 'use' is supposed to support "Any...graphical element...", line included.  Well, line doesn't have x,y,width or height attributes; it has x1, y1, x2, y2.

Also this would preclude passing in all sorts of other attributes like stroke, stroke-width, etc.

Is the use statement really limited to just x,y,width, and height or is there another way to get attributes merged into the def template node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since line is neither an `<svg>` element nor a `<symbol>` element it is covered here:

*In the generated content, the ‘use’ will be replaced by ‘g’, where all attributes from the ‘use’ element except for ‘x’, ‘y’, ‘width’, ‘height’ and ‘xlink:href’ are transferred to the generated ‘g’ element. An additional transformation translate(x,y) is appended to the end (i.e., right-side) of the ‘transform’ attribute on the generated ‘g’, where x and y represent the values of the ‘x’ and ‘y’ attributes on the ‘use’ element. The referenced object and its contents are deep-cloned into the generated tree.*

So width and height are ignored and x and y become ways to translate the line. That's basically all you can do with it.

Comment: Well, that's frustrating.  However, this line of thought and questioning had a silver lining: I researched the <path> element as a possible replacement for <line> re-use.  WOW, what a file size difference using path commands (M,L) to draw my lines as opposed to use statements.  I should maybe have stated that my reason for wanting to re-use a line node was to keep file size as small as possible.  <path> is the obvious winner.